# Seed SQL table with data when the FK value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues with seeding a database that has FK column that can be NULL in the data.
This is a general data set built to show the issue as the original table is rather large.

There are two tables being referenced as FK, the Location and Alert tables. Alert also has a FK reference to the Location table.

Table Location

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [LocationUk] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Location] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LocationUk] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and its data:

| LocationUk | LocationName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | North |
| 2 | South |
| 3 | East |
| 4 | West |

Table Alert

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Alert](
    [AlertUk] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AlertID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AlertName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LocationUk] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Alert] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AlertUk] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alert]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Alert_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationUk])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([LocationUk])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alert] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Alert_Location]
GO
```

and its data:

| AlertUk | AlertID | AlertName | LocationUk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00 | Alert1 | 1 |
| 2 | 01 | Alert2 | 1 |
| 3 | 02 | Alert3 | 1 |
| 4 | 03 | Alert4 | 1 |
| 5 | 00 | Alert1 | 2 |
| 6 | 01 | Alert2 | 2 |
| 7 | 02 | Alert3 | 2 |
| 8 | 03 | Alert4 | 2 |
| 9 | 00 | Alert1 | 3 |
| 10 | 01 | Alert2 | 3 |
| 11 | 02 | Alert3 | 3 |
| 12 | 03 | Alert4 | 3 |
| 13 | 00 | Alert1 | 4 |
| 14 | 01 | Alert2 | 4 |
| 15 | 02 | Alert3 | 4 |
| 16 | 03 | Alert4 | 4 |

And this is the table I am having issues seeding data into:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OutOfService] [bit] NULL,
    [AlertUk] [int] NULL,
    [LocationUk] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Alert] FOREIGN KEY([AlertUk])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Alert] ([AlertUk])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Alert]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationUk])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([LocationUk])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Location]
GO
```

with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE #ItemsTemp
(
    ItemName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    OutOfService bit NULL,
    AlertID varchar(50) NULL,
    LocationID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO #ItemsTemp
(   ItemName,OutOfService,AlertID,LocationID    )
VALUES
('Item1',0,NULL,'North'),
('Item2',0,'00','North'),
('Item3',1,'00','South'),
('Item4',0,NULL,'West')

MERGE INTO dbo.Items AS target
USING 
(
    SELECT 
        I.ItemName AS ItemName,
        I.OutOfService AS OutOfService,
        A.AlertUk AS AlertUk,
        L.LocationUk AS LocationUk
    FROM #ItemsTemp I
    JOIN dbo.Location L
        ON L.LocationName = I.LocationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Alert A
        ON A.AlertID = I.AlertID
        WHERE A.LocationUk = L.LocationUk
) AS source
    ON source.ItemName = target.ItemName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT
    (
        ItemName,
        OutOfService,
        AlertUk,
        LocationUk
    )
    VALUES
    (
        source.ItemName,
        source.OutOfService,
        source.AlertUk,
        source.LocationUk
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE
;

DROP TABLE #ItemsTemp

PRINT 'completed'
```

This script returns this:

> (4 rows affected)
>
> (2 rows affected)
> completed

I know the problem is with the null values when attempting to resolve this part of the script

```
INNER JOIN dbo.Alert A
ON A.AlertID = I.AlertID
WHERE A.LocationUk = L.LocationUk
```

I have tried a join, inner join, and left join to attempt to resolve this and get all rows into the table. What can I change within the script for it to enter all 4 rows into the table? This general data has 4 columns and 4 rows, but the actual data set runs into the thousands and has many more columns.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I was going to help, because I thought you had provided a full [MRE] but realise you're missing the Location and Alert tables to run an example.

Comment: Anyway I imagine the issue is either the fact that you are doing an inner join, which requires a matching row, or `A.AlertID = I.AlertID` which won't work for a null compare. Pull that select query out and make sure its working as you require.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. You mention foreign keys, but there aren't any table definitions. The more I look at this the less clear it becomes. At the very least provide table definitions and sample data. Then explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why do you JOIN #ItemsTemp with a lot of other tables? Can't you just use #ItemsTemp as source and then do your merge thing? Once you join a lot of other tables, you lose some rows

Comment: I believe all you need to change is `INNER JOIN dbo.Alert A` to `LEFT JOIN dbo.Alert A`. This will allow the null `AlertID` values to be inserted with null `AlertUk` values.  However, it will also do the same for other unrecognized `AlertID` values like `'foo'`. To protect against that, you may need to add the condition `AND NOT (I.AlertID IS NOT NULL AND L.AlertUk IS NULL)`.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the question @DaleK. I'm not sure how removing that line would allow me seed that column with any data. I do understand the null compare won't work as it is, but that is what I am trying to resolve.

Comment: @TN I have tried both an inner and left join, but neither works. I did try to add the provided AND NOT statement, but there is no AlertUk in the L table. I changed it to this: ```AND NOT (I.AlertID IS NOT NULL AND A.AlertID IS NULL)``` and this ```AND NOT (A.AlertID IS NOT NULL AND I.AlertID IS NULL)``` but neither way worked.

Comment: I just noticed that you also have a `WHERE` clause that will only be true for non-null values.  If you also change the `WHERE` to an `AND`, that condition will become part of the `LEFT JOIN ... ON ...` condition and you should then get all four records. The optional condition I suggested order would then be `WHERE NOT (I.AlertID IS NOT NULL AND A.AlertUk IS NULL)`, but it is up to you to decide if you need this or not.   See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xTcz4nvy) that shows the `SELECT...` portion of your merge before and after both changes. I also included an extra test data row.

Comment: @TN Thank you! I thought I had tried a ```LEFT JOIN ... ON ... AND ...``` but I must have only done that with a ```JOIN```. I'm not sure if I'll need the ```WHERE``` but thanks for also giving me the suggested order for if I end up using it. This is much simpler than the nested ```SELECT``` route that I was investigating.